# Is there a way to set icon(drawable) on button loaded from URL?

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to set an icon on my button which is loaded from URL. There is a method which works if the drawable already exists in `R`:

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds();
```

but what should I do with image loading from web?

Comment: you may use this method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) which accepts the `Drawable`s. Load the images as bitmaps from the internet, create `BitmapDrawable`s from them, and then use them in the method above.

Comment: I have done this but the method "setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()" input is int not BitmapDrawables  so I get error, 
  Bitmap theBitmap =
                Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/easter-egg-bunny/256/red-cute-icon.png").submit().get();
        Drawable iconDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), theBitmap);
        button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iconDrawable,0,0,0);

Comment: yes, like that.but instead of `0` use `null`, as those are not the resource IDs, but drawables

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks :)

Comment: Can I change icon size in this situation?

Comment: try changing the bitmap size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) You need to create a Picasso `Target`, load the image from the URL into the target and call `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()` on the TextView with the Bitmap from the `onBitmapLoaded` callback of Picasso Target.

You need to also keep in mind that the Picasso Targets are [weakly referenced](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/83) so you need to be careful and keep strong references to your target.

Here is implemented a widget called [PicassoTargetableTextView](https://gist.github.com/prashand/8b4223c7f96c7d5e300655c82f731b9c) that does all of that. You can use the `PicassoTargetableTextView.load(left, top, right, bottom)` to load drawables into the TextView at runtime.